# Capturar TouchEvent do aparelho para usá-lo na tela

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

Tenho o seguinte código Javascript, porém ele não captura os comandos de touch, alguém sabe o por que?
Se estou utilizando alguma sintaxe incorreta ou algo do tipo?

```js
  private capturarEventoTouch(componente: HTMLCanvasElement) {
    // Mousedown = Clique esquerdo
    fromEvent(componente, 'touchstart')
      .pipe(
        switchMap((e) => {
          return fromEvent(componente, 'touchmove')
            .pipe(
              // Mouseup = Release do clique esquerdo
              takeUntil(fromEvent(componente, 'touchend')),
              // Mouseleave = Quando o mouse sai da área do Componente
              takeUntil(fromEvent(componente, 'touchleave')),
              pairwise()
            );
        })
      )
      .subscribe((res: [TouchEvent, TouchEvent]) => {
        const rect = componente.getBoundingClientRect();

        const posicaoAnterior = {
          x: res[0].touches[0].clientX - rect.left,
          y: res[0].touches[0].clientY - rect.top
        };

        const posicaoAtual = {
          x: res[1].touches[1].clientX - rect.left,
          y: res[1].touches[1].clientY - rect.top
        };

        this.desenharNoCanvas(posicaoAnterior, posicaoAtual);
      });
  }
```

Comment: se vc colocar um console log ele nem entra no subscribe??

Comment: Edu ele entra no subscribe, mas agora diz que clientX é undefined ...

Comment: res é undefined tambem? Tenta gerar um stackblitz para ficar mais facil de responder

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei o erro galera preciso estar utilizando apenas o index [1] só no res; E estava utilizando no touches também o código corrigido ficou assim:

```
const posicaoAnterior = {
  x: res[0].touches[0].clientX - rect.left,
  y: res[0].touches[0].clientY - rect.top
};

const posicaoAtual = {
      x: res[1].touches[0].clientX - rect.left,
      y: res[1].touches[0].clientY - rect.top
};
```